# Grafana provision elasticsearch datastore over ansible

Tags: elasticsearch, ansible, grafana

Anybody can advise how to map the configuration properties seen in the Grafana UI to their equivalents in the configuration file over Ansible?

This is what I have that is working well:

```
      grafana_datasources:
        - name: elasticsearch
          type: elasticsearch
          access: server
          database: "metricbeat-7.5.2"
          url: 'http://localhost:9200'
          readOnly: false
          editable: true
          basicAuth: false
          jsonData:
            timeField: "@timestamp"
            esVersion: 70
            maxConcurrentShardRequests: 5
```

I managed to set up everything except Auth section. Actually I setup only "Basic auth" field by adding "basicAuth: false". Now I am stuck with setting up the following fields:

- TLS Client Auth
- Skip TLS Verify
- Forward OAuth Identity

I tried with adding:

```
tlsAuth: false  
tlsAuthWithCACert: false 
tlsSkipVerify: false
```

but nothing happens. I also tried with adding the same to jsonData but still no luck...

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
Dragan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I resolved this. In order to get these three fields I added the following to my playbook:

`isDefault: false`

How I figured it out? Well, I created a dashboard manually and then exported it to json with the following command:

```
mkdir -p data_sources && curl -s "http://localhost:3000/api/datasources"  -u admin:password | jq -c -M '.[]'|split -l 1 - data_sources/
```

Then I edited exported dashboard json file and found out the key and the value I used in my playbook.

Cheers